# Constructively founded set of axioms for real analysis

Tags: reference-request, foundations, constructive-mathematics

Is there a workable set of axioms for doing real analysis and for which it is proven that there is a model in one of the better researched constructive foundational theories (e.g. CZF or IZF set theories)? For example, using the groups of axioms $R1$, $R2$ and $R3$ from Douglas Bridges' "Constructive mathematics: a foundation for computable analysis", there should be an IZF-model or a CZF-model $M$ so that $M \models R1 \wedge R2 \wedge R3$.

Considering that CZF was designed to do Bishop-style constructive analysis on the top of it, it appears that this must be possible. But I wonder if this was already done somewhere, considering that it would be much more convenient to work on a high level using axioms for analysis, knowing that they are well-founded on one of the foundational theories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a theorem of ECST + BRA (a subsystem of CZF set theory) that there is an Archimedean Dedekind-complete (R3) pseudo-ordered (R2) field (R1). See e.g. [Section 7.3](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/book.pdf) in the Aczel-Rathjen constructive set theory notes.

If you extend CZF with countable choice, you get that the "Cauchy" and "Dedekind" reals coincide, and there is a Cauchy-complete Archimedean pseudo-ordered field (in fact uniquely up to isomorphism). For more on the relationship between "Cauchy" and "Dedekind" reals, see the Lubarsky-Rathjen article [On the Constructive Dedekind Reals](http://math.fau.edu/lubarsky/Dedreals.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure about the implications of Cauchy and Dedekind reals not coinciding, which is relevant to me since I'm sceptic about choice principles. But I did not specify what axioms must be present. So I'm about to accept this answer, just waiting if someone comes up with a different example.